Django can not render a `QuerySet`
I have created the feedback app on learning system however I can not render the feedback page that returns feedback details. When I click the feedback link it does not return anything as shown below.

Below is the view.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from accounts.models import User


def feedback_view(request):
    feedback_data = User.objects.filter(username=request.user)

    context = {
        "feedback_data": feedback_data
    }
    return render(request, "feedback/feedback.html", context)


@property
def feedback_save(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        messages.error(request, "Invalid Method.")
        return redirect('feedback')
    else:
        feedback = request.POST.get('feedback_message')
        feedback_data = User.objects.get(username=request.user.id)

        try:
            add_feedback = FeedBack(username=feedback_data, feedback=feedback, feedback_reply="")
            add_feedback.save()
            messages.success(request, "Feedback Sent.")
            return redirect('feedback')
        except:
            messages.error(request, "Failed to Send Feedback.")
            return redirect('feedback')

model.py:
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class FeedbackMessage(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feedback = models.TextField()
    feedback_reply = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

feedback.html:
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block page_title %}
    Feedback Message
{% endblock page_title %}
{% load static %}

{% block main_content %}
this is a test
<section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <!-- general form elements -->
                    <div class="card card-primary">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Leave a Feedback Message</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-header -->

                                {% comment %} Display Messages {% endcomment %}
                                {% if messages %}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    {% for message in messages %}
                                    {% if message.tags == "error" %}
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                        {{ message }}
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        </div>
                                    {% elif message.tags == "success" %}
                                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                        {{ message }}
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        </div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            
                    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'staff_feedback_save' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="card-body">
                           
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Feedback Message </label>
                                <textarea name="feedback_message" class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Feedback Message"></textarea>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card-body -->

                        <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Leave a Feedback</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card -->



                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card card-success">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Feedback History</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body">
                           <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead class="thead-light">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#ID</th>
                                        <th>Feedback Message</th>
                                        <th>Feedback Reply</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    
                                    {% for row in feedback_data %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ row.feedback }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ row.feedback_reply }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card-body -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </section>

  {% endblock main_content %}

{% block custom_js %}

{% endblock custom_js %}

I expect the app should return the feedback of each user in a row and the reply cell at the end.

OK, your code doesn't do what you expected it to do. What does it do? What exactly gets executed and what are the values of the variables involved?

I would first be weary of using the property decorator outside a class.

Your code has too many issues. .filter(username=request.user) won't return any rows because request.user is a User instance, not a string. Your feedback_data is an empty queryset. Besides you are filtering User objects, not FeedbackMessage which doesn't make any sense. Your feedback_save view is trying to create instances of the FeedBack class, but that class doesn't exist. Your User foreign key is named user_id (which is also a no-no) but the rest of your code assumes that it is username.

There are multiple issues with your code.
Main issue is you are querying the wrong model.
Your user's feedbacks are stored in the FeedbackMessage model but you are querying the User model.
Query  FeedbackMessage model:
feedback_data = FeedbackMessage.objects.filter(user_id=request.user)


Other issues

As @Chukwujiobi Canon mentioned, You can't use @property decorator on functions, you should use it with class methods
{% load static %} you had better define load static at the top of your template
Django automatically creates certain fields on your model, so you don't have to explicitly define them. Take a look at the Django docs for further information.

